# Which catagory for CFA/CAIA/FRM/CMT exams in Area 51?

Tags: discussion

Which catagory do you think is the most appropriate asking questions about CFA/CAIA/FRM/CMT exams?

Do you think it should be filed under business or under professional?

Comment: *Scratches head* I forgot if you should be asking here or not, but I think I would question the legitimacy of the proposal first.

Comment: Where can I find more about the legitimacy of the proposal?

Comment: Could you expand the abbreviations you are using, please?  Country Fire Authority might be the first one ...

Comment: They are all qualifications in the Financial Services industry. CFA is Chartered Financial Analyst for instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I ask finance questions that seem to fall in between the scope of the two existing sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268614/where-can-i-ask-finance-questions-that-seem-to-fall-in-between-the-scope-of-the)

Comment: How is it duplicate? That question was asking where can I ask a QUESTION about a specific subject. This questions ask very clearly which category should a new site about these four financial certifications should be created under in Area 51. If no one wish to direct me, I'm just going to go ahead and create it under Business category. Thanks for your help guys....

Comment: What we mean is, your questions all have the same answer, you seem to be looking for a site that requires a lower level of expertise/experience than Quantitative Finance and it doesn't exist. Good luck with your Area 51 proposal.

Answer (score 3):

Given that these are professional financial qualifications, such questions are most likely to be on topic on the [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site.

It all depends on the question though, if you "ask what are the exams like?" or something equally broad and opinion based you'll likely get pretty short shrift there. If, however you are working in Quantitative Finance and studying towards one of these exams as part of your work then your question might be on topic.

Check the [help centre](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and search for questions that might be similar to the ones you want to ask on the site first to make sure.

Comment: Asking such a question [did not work out so well for our gallant OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268614/where-can-i-ask-finance-questions-that-seem-to-fall-in-between-the-scope-of-the).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Hmm, he does seem to be asking the same question again and again in the hope of getting a different answer.

Comment: My take is that this question here is about where to put an Area 51 proposal for a site that would take the question, per the previous meta discussion.